# product of spaces of bounded linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a normed space. Let $(F_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of normed spaces. Show that
$\prod_{i \in I}{\mathcal{L}(E, F_i)}$ and $\mathcal{L}(E,\prod_{i \in I}F_i)$ are isometrically isomorphic.

I'm really struggling with the concept of the product, and have no idea how to go about this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to problems with products, first think about the case $I:=\{1,2\}$. Then an element of $\prod_{i\in I}\mathcal L(E,F_i)$ can be written as $(T_1,T_2)$, where $T_i\in \mathcal L(E,F_i)$. 
We can define for $x\in E$, 
$$(\varphi(T_1,T_2))(x):=(T_1(x),T_2(x))$$
This gives a isometric isomorphic map between $\prod_{i\in I}\mathcal L(E,F_i)$ and $\mathcal L\left(E,\prod_{i\in I}F_i\right)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why that is an isometric isomorphism?

Comment: It depends on the norm you put on the product, for example on $\prod_{i\in I}\mathcal L(E,F_i)$ you can put $\sup_{i\in I}\norm{T_i}_{\mathcal L(E,F_i)}$.